# Vb.net Decrypt sha512 hash

Tags: vb.net, winforms, encryption, sha512

Heys guys,

I'm struggling about out to decrypt the hash how my `sha512` encryption. I'm searching a way to finnaly decrypt it.

By the way this is how I do the encryption:

```
Dim uEncode As New UTF8Encoding()
        Dim bytClearString() As Byte = uEncode.GetBytes("to encrypt")
        Dim sha As New  _
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed
        Dim WordEncrypt As String = ""
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha.ComputeHash(bytClearString)
        For Each b As Byte In hash
            WordEncrypt &= b.ToString("x2")
        Next
```

What i need now is to know how to decrypt it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHA512 is not an encryption algorithm, it's a hashing algorithm. What this means is that the data that goes into it cannot be recovered from the generated hash.

I'm sorry but there is no way short of using a rainbow table style lookup to get the original data back. There's a [great post on the difference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms) on SO.

Comment: @JoSav, Since the rainbow table would be of infinite length you'd only be able to calculate the possible answers so far. As computers become sufficiently powerful it will become trivial to calculate the shortest possibilities or someone, smarter than me, will work out how to short circuit SHA512. Either way, waiting should be combined with the development of a suitably more complex hashing algorithm.